# Running Tape with a Webpack Alias

Tags: javascript, webpack, tap

I'm having issues getting Tape to work properly with a Webpack alias.

Within my `webpack.config.js` file I have the following alias, which works when I initiate my app with Storybook:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './components'),
  },
  extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.css',
      '.scss',
      '.png',
      '.jpg',
      '.gif',
      '.jpeg',
  ],
},
```

I'm initiating Tape in my package.json file as a node script like so:

```
"testSingle": "NODE_ENV=test tape -r @babel/register -r ./utils-for-tests/configureEnzyme.js -r jsdom-global/register -r ignore-styles",
```

However with this I'm getting the following error whenever I run my tests:

```
Error: Cannot find module '~/atoms/ArrowIcon/ArrowIcon'
```

Is there a way I can register Tape with webpack so it recognizes the aliases prior to running the tests?